# What happened to my file? Now has this weird ghosting effect on the Geo in the viewport

Tags: rendering

All of a sudden my geo went weird on me. It could be a rendering thing - I have no idea? I am fairly new to Blender?
Its not Xray Toggle. Rendered in Cycles[image] (Even looks the same)
(version 3.01 Windows)
any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your mesh is very very far away from the world origin.

The further an object is from the world origin the harder it becomes for Blender to accurately calculate it's position, this usually starts becoming visible at around 5,000 meters away from world origin, aka 5k units.

your object shows us it's 3,884,704 units away from the world origin, which is a lot, so Blender has a reaally bad time calculating it, even the grid guidelines are freaking out.

Dragging your object back to the world origin will fix this, use Alt G to reset it

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply, I will try this now. Cheers